# Finding Functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Find the number of functions $f:S→S$ such that $f(f(x))=f(x)$ for all $x∈S$. How do I approach this problem? I have no idea(I kept putting values).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)=f(f(x))$ implies the range of $f$ is the set of elements $x$ such that $x=f(x)$.

To count the functions first select the range (The elements in $x$ so that $f(x)=x$).

Once you have done that you can map the other elements to any of the fixed points.

So when the range has size $i$ there are $\binom{5}{i}$ ways to select the range and then $i^{5-i}$ ways to select where to map the $5-i$ non fixed points.

Hence you want $\sum\limits_{i=1}^5 \binom{5}{i}i^{5-i}=5+80+90+20+1=196$

Answer (score 0):

Well, say $f(x) = y$. Then you want to find $f$ such that $f(y) = y$. How many functions are there such that $f(y) = y$ for every $y \in S$?

Comment: We want $f(x)=f(f(x))$. Not necessarily $x=f(x)$